# Where to get separate Visual C++ compiler for Windows SDK 8?

Tags: visual-c++

In [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) 8 "Visual C++ Compilers and C Runtime (CRT)" was removed:

> The following items were either changed or removed from this version of the Windows SDK.
>
> 1. **Command-line Build Environment** The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. The Windows SDK now requires a compiler and build environment to be installed separately.

Where can I get these separately, without downloading Visual Studio? I want to get old command line build environment, but can't find download link.

Comment: I don't think you can. You have to download Visual Studio, the Express version is still free. You can do a custom install if you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build C++/C# created with Visual Studio 2012 without VS 2012 being installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810384/build-c-c-created-with-visual-studio-2012-without-vs-2012-being-installed)

Comment: what microsoft done ?! for recompiling tow sources of total length in ~50 lines i must download and install visual studio... Nevertheless, thaks all.

Comment: You've always had to download one or the other (VS or the SDK). Now you just *have* to download VS. Not that big of a deal. There are online compilers if you just want to test a snippet of code.

Comment: @CodyGray the SDK is (to my knowledge) free to download, whereas visual studio is certainly not :-(

Comment: @OrionEdwards - Visual Studio Express is free. See http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx and http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8 for c++ capable version and can be used for commercial use i believe

Answer (score 2):

http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8

This is the Express edition page for Visual Studio 2013. These can all be installed at the same time to give Web/Store/Desktop/Console based application development.

They can be used for commercial purposes and also download as ISO files for reinstall at a later time.

You can install the desktop version and select what components to install to get a copy of the visual C++ compiler installed. This applies for the 2010 editions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Command-line build environment is now available as the Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools and can be downloaded from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

> These tools allow you to build C++ libraries and applications
>   targeting Windows desktop. They are the same tools that you find in
>   Visual Studio 2015 in a scriptable standalone installer. Now you only
>   need to download the tools you need to build C++ projects.

Comment: Dead link. -----