# Non-existing identifier used as default argument in non-instantiated function template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Today I found a piece of code equivalent to the following:

```
enum X
{
    x1 = 0,
    x2 = 1
};

template<typename T>
void bar(T obj, X x = x3) { }
//                    ^^
//                    This identifier is bogus!

int main() { }
```

Both VC10 and VC12 happily compile it. Both clang 3.4 and GCC 4.8.1 reject it (which is what I would expect).

Is this a bug, or is VC's behavior actually allowed by the Standard? If so, which are the relevant paragraphs?

Comment: wow, interesting what assembler VS generates for that

Comment: Just a note - VC _18_ (VS 2013) rejects the this code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: What's VC 18?

Comment: @AndyProwl The version of the compiler shipped with VS.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: That's VC12 AFAIK. And I'm using VS2013 and it does compile it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andy: Check the version string of "Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler" when you run `cl.exe`, it's been increasing since before the product name changes from "Microsoft C/C++" to "Microsoft Visual C++".  IIRC, Microsoft C/C++ reached version 7.0 and was followed by Visual C++ 1.0

Comment: @Ben: Ah, thank you, that clarifies. So what's the correct way to refer to the Visual C++ compiler that comes with VS2010 and VS2013? I thought it was "VC10" and "VC12".

Comment: (still, I'm using VS2013 and it does compile this snippet)

Comment: @Andy: VS2012 (VS 11.0) comes with "Visual C++ 2012", also version 11.0, and using the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler 17.0. The DLLs are named MSVCR110, matching the Visual Studio version number, not the compiler release number.  I suppose that 17.0 shouldn't be paired with abbreviations VS or VC or MSVC, but if you were for example reporting an internal compiler error, you'd definitely want that version string, expressed perhaps as `CL.EXE 17.00.61030 x86`

Comment: @Ben: By "VC12" I meant the compiler that comes with VS2013 (consistently with the numbering used by S. T. Lavavej e.g. [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753115/)). I've actually never seen the numbers 17 or 18 being mentioned when referring to a version of the VC compiler (I've always read "... VC10, VC11, VC12"). Might be time to change that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a well-known fact that VC doesn't have two-phase lookup. That means it accepts all sorts of [bogosity](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bogosity.html) in templates, as long as it at least looks like syntactically valid C++ and it is not actually instantiated.

This is just one more of those instances.

As you can see in their [conformance roadmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx), two-phase lookup is planned for sometime after the post-RTM CTP, which I guess would mean you will have access to it after you pay for the next iteration of the Visual Studio suite.

As for the Standard references, 14.6/9-10 say:

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template definition, the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) are used for non-dependent names. [...]
>
> If a name does not depend on a template-parameter (as defined in 14.6.2), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template definition.

Comment: @Xeo: [Compiler is no longer in the Windows SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078755/where-to-get-separate-visual-c-compiler-for-windows-sdk-8)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, good to know. It's still available for free through the free VS version, though.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, and with Visual Studio "multi-targeting support", it might just be possible to use that newer compiler with older but more complete paid editions.  No guarantees though.