# Does Windows come with Visual C++ compiler when it's first installed, and is it needed to compile f2py modules?

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, pip, f2py

there,

I've developed a Python package (https://github.com/pedrosecchi67/LovelacePM) which makes intensive use of f2py to speed up calculations. It was installed and ran smoothly on Ubuntu from day 1 and pip had no trouble using the setup.py script to compile Fortran extensions.

When I first tried using pip to install it on my Windows machine, however, I had an installation error reporting that Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 was not found and had to be installed in order to compile the same modules.

I used to have VS Community installed until about a year ago, but removed most of its suite because I stopped using it and wanted to save disk space - and I'm afraid I might have uninstalled the compiler along with it. I don't know if it was a default Windows feature or a part of VS Community, though.

My question is: does Visual C++ Compiler come installed on Windows by default? 
I need to know whether or not my package's users will be able to install it on a Windows machine without previously installing the compiler from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ is part of Visual Studio, not of Windows. It is a separate product line with separate versions, maintained by a separate team. VS Community 2019 is the latest free version of Visual Studio, and still comes with the 14.0 compiler. (as well as 14.1 and 14.2)

The closest you could get was a command-line compiler in the Windows SDK (Software Development Kit). [But that has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078755/where-to-get-separate-visual-c-compiler-for-windows-sdk-8). You can still get the Visual Studio Build Tools without the whole IDE.

Comment: So that implies anyone installing the package would have to previously install the compiler, is that right? =( that’s kind of annoying... I wish I could have used f2py without implying the need for any third party installation

Comment: @PedroSecchi: Well, you have to understand what sort of hack f2py is. Python is an interpreted language, Fortran is a compiled language, and you somehow need to glue that together. Microsoft has had a solution for that sort of problems for the last 30 years (COM), but Linux comes from the Unix corner where that doesn't exist.